# What does "save(false)" do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the following code, what does `save(false)` do?

```
def create_reset_code!  
    @reset = true  
    self.attributes = {:reset_code => Digest::SHA1.hexdigest( Time.now.to_s.split(//).sort_by {rand}.join )}  
    save(false)  
  end
```

If it's for updating the credentials, then why do they include `false`?

Comment: For those using Rails 3.x: `save(false)` has been replaced by `save(:validate => false)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`save(false)` bypasses validations for the model object being saved.

Answer (score 8):

Old Rails version:

```
save(false)
```

New Rails version [per the docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save):

```
save(validate: false)
```